# Lora Ra-02(SX1278) Module Maximum Transmission Distance (Non LOS)

Tags: microcontroller, rf, lora, sx1276

I was trying Lora Communication for a Project and i m having trouble getting the required range. Im using an [Ra-02 module](https://www.sunrom.com/p/lora-rf-module-ra-02-sx1278-433-mhz-spi-wireless-transceiver-ipex) (433Mhz) with [antenna](https://www.sunrom.com/p/433-mhz-antenna-3db-5cm-straight-sma-male)(433MHz 3db 5cm) and i was able to get a 300m range(Not line of sight). I also tried the Helical antenna model Ra-01 but results were almost same(240m). The code i referred to is [this](https://github.com/wdomski/SX1278). Im also attaching my initialization, send receive functions here.

```
void SX1278_Configure(SX1278_t *module,uint8_t frequency, uint8_t power,uint8_t Spreadfactor,uint8_t Bandwidth){
SX1278_Sleep(module);
HAL_Delay(15);
SX1278_LoraMode(module);
//SX1278_WriteRegister(module, 0x5904); //?? Change digital regulator form 1.6V to 1.47V: see errata note

SX1278_BurstWriteRegisters(LR_RegFrMsb,(uint8_t*) SX1278_Frequency[frequency], 3);
SX1278_WriteRegister(LR_RegPaConfig,power);//Setting output power parameter
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegOcp, 0x0B);         //RegOcp,Close Ocp
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegLna, 0x23);     //RegLNA,High & LNA Enable
if(Spreadfactor == 6)
    {
            uint8_t tmp;
            SX1278_WriteRegister(LR_RegModemConfig1,((Bandwidth << 4) + (SX1278_CR << 1) + 0x01)); //Implicit Enable, & Error Coding rate 4/5(0x01), 4/6(0x02), 4/7(0x03), 4/8(0x04)

            SX1278_WriteRegister(LR_RegModemConfig2,((Spreadfactor << 4) + (SX1278_CRC << 2)+ 0x03));//SF,CRC Enable(0x02) 
            tmp = SX1278_ReadRegister( 0x31);
            tmp &= 0xF8;
            tmp |= 0x05;
            SX1278_WriteRegister( 0x31, tmp);
            SX1278_WriteRegister( 0x37, 0x0C);
    }
else
    {
            SX1278_WriteRegister(LR_RegModemConfig1,((Bandwidth << 4) + (SX1278_CR << 1) + 0x00)); //Explicit Enable CRC Enable(0x02) & Error Coding rate 4/5(0x01), 4/6(0x02), 4/7(0x03), 4/8(0x04)
            SX1278_WriteRegister(LR_RegModemConfig2,((Spreadfactor<< 4) + (SX1278_CRC << 2)+ 0x03)); //SFactor &  LNA gain set by the internal AGC loop

    }
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegSymbTimeoutLsb, 0xFF); //RegSymbTimeoutLsb Timeout = 0x3FF(Max)
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegPreambleMsb, 0x00); //RegPreambleMsb
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegPreambleLsb, 12); //RegPreambleLsb 8+4=12byte Preamble
SX1278_WriteRegister( REG_LR_DIOMAPPING2, 0x01); //RegDioMapping2 DIO5=00, DIO4=01
module->readBytes = 0;
SX1278_Standby(module); //Entry standby mode
```

}

```
int SX1278_LoRaSetAsRx(SX1278_t * module, uint8_t length, uint32_t timeout)//set mod as rx
{
uint8_t addr;

module->packetLength = length;

SX1278_DefaultConfiguration(module);        //Setting base parameter
SX1278_WriteRegister( REG_LR_PADAC, 0x84);  //Normal and RX
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegHopPeriod, 0xFF);   //No FHSS
SX1278_WriteRegister( REG_LR_DIOMAPPING1, 0x01);//DIO=00,DIO1=00,DIO2=00, DIO3=01
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegIrqFlagsMask, 0x3F);//Open RxDone interrupt & Timeout
SX1278_ClearInterrupt(module);
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegPayloadLength, length);//Payload Length 21byte(this register must difine when the data long of one byte in SF is 6)
addr = SX1278_ReadRegister(LR_RegFifoRxBaseAddr); //Read RxBaseAddr
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegFifoAddrPtr, addr); //RxBaseAddr->FiFoAddrPtr
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegOpMode, 0x8d);  //Mode//Low Frequency Mode
//SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegOpMode,0x05); //Continuous Rx Mode //High Frequency Mode
module->readBytes = 0;

while (1) {
    if ((SX1278_ReadRegister( LR_RegModemStat) & 0x04) == 0x04) {   //Rx-on going RegModemStat
        module->status = RX;
        return 1;
    }
    if (--timeout == 0) {
        SX1278_Reset();
        SX1278_DefaultConfiguration(module);
        return 0;
    }
    HAL_Delay(1);
}
```

}

```
int SX1278_LoRaSetAsTx(SX1278_t * module, uint8_t length, uint32_t timeout) {
uint8_t addr;
uint8_t temp;

module->packetLength = length;

SX1278_DefaultConfiguration(module); //setting base parameter
SX1278_WriteRegister( REG_LR_PADAC, 0x87);  //Tx for 20dBm          0x07 ? +20dBm on PA_BOOST when OutputPower=1111
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegHopPeriod, 0x00); //RegHopPeriod NO FHSS
SX1278_WriteRegister( REG_LR_DIOMAPPING1, 0x41); //DIO0=01, DIO1=00,DIO2=00, DIO3=01
SX1278_ClearInterrupt(module);
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegIrqFlagsMask, 0xF7); //Open TxDone interrupt
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegPayloadLength, length); //RegPayloadLength 21byte
addr = SX1278_ReadRegister(LR_RegFifoTxBaseAddr); //RegFiFoTxBaseAddr
SX1278_WriteRegister( LR_RegFifoAddrPtr, addr); //RegFifoAddrPtr

while (1) {
    temp = SX1278_ReadRegister( LR_RegPayloadLength);
    if (temp == length) {
        module->status = TX;
        return 1;
    }

    if (--timeout == 0) {
        SX1278_Reset();
        SX1278_DefaultConfiguration(module);
        return 0;
    }
}}
```

My doubt is if i have done any configuration mistakes. I used 20dbm, spreadfactor 8 and bandwidth 20.8Khz and i m able to get everything working even with 255 characters. Is this the practical range for this module without LOS or can i improve the range. Can you check on the code and guide me. Thank You

Comment: "Not line of sight" means anything from paper thin walls in between to a faraday cage.

Comment: Is it calibrated for centre f error? and sensitivity threshold vs specs? if not where is source of interference? radiated? conducted? calibration?  then after calibration and noise mitigation compare Friis loss calc with your results. If not close, which assumption is wrong? (calibrate it)

Comment: I tested along a curved path so there are trees and concrete walls covering the path partially. I haven't done any calibration .Just used the readily available ra-02 modules

Comment: Do the calibration. if you have instruments. If you don't, use smallest spread factor and sweep with weakest  signal to find Rx Xtal centre capture range. is where it should be.  Make sure Vcc is noise , ripple free , and do Friis loss CALC online so you understand tradeoffs of Range for each parameter. Then report back dB error or range error from theoretical Whats wrong with your Helix? Bad coax?  is SF=8 the max for that rate? with 500kHz BW. That depends on centre f XTAL error, Do whatever is necessary to get Line of  Site.!  Avoid Rician fading loss !!